# How can we define the html layout as per UX? what is semantic html as per UX?

Tags: user-behavior, accessibility, html, semantics

I am new to this UX, How it defines the user experience, how to implement user experience in HTML layout? What is semantic html in terms of UX view point. Does it help to improve my site accessibility by using ux.

My need: any once can tell me how to implement the html in proper way. for example disability person need to access my webpage. in that case semantic html help for that people. so correct html element is correct place how to code or write? for this experiences(ux) required or not?

Comment: Hi, welcome to UX.SE! Could you clarify your question a bit, because it feels to me like you are asking multiple things. Do you want to know how to implement UX into HTML as in make your code accessible for other developers? Or do you want to make the UX of your website better?

Comment: Ux for accessibility for all the people and usage of html tags in exact place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user experience has very little to do with code - all your users will have an experience using your solution (so do you want them to have a good experience or a poor experience?)

Semantic html just means you are using html correctly as specified by the W3C, e.g. if you need a heading you should use `<h1>` - `<h6>` vs make a `<p>` look like a heading by making it bold and 18px using CSS.

The main value of Semantic html is you get some degree of Accessibility support for free, i.e. so do not create a custom widget if there is already a native html element with the semantics and behaviour you need (e.g. do not create a custom radio button by styling a standard button and making it look and behave like a radio button - the EXTjs framework actually did this).

However, there is a lot more to Accessibility than semantic html, but if accessibility is important,  writing html as per the W3C HTML specification (semantic html) will help you, as will learning about WCAG 2.0 and ARIA 1.0.